# Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 0 in

Tags: php

Hello can some 1 help me out with this ?

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 0 in .. at line 112

this is at that line !

```
if(preg_match("/%/", $url) || preg_match("/;/", $url) || preg_match("/)/", $url))
```

i already changed something at this point

This is the reall code befor adding !

```
if(preg_match("%", $url) || preg_match(";", $url) || preg_match(")", $url))
```

i hope some 1 can help me out here !

kind regards
ropin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape parentheses because These are Special character in regex.

```
if(preg_match("/%/", $url) || preg_match("/;/", $url) || preg_match("/\)/", $url))
```

Answer (score 5):

You would have to escape parentheses in your regex, but I think what would be simpler is this:

```
if(preg_match("/(%|;|\))/", $url))
```